# Remove item from NSMutableArray from PLIST

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist

I have a plist which contains a number of quiz item are pulled randomly by using arc4random (), I want to remove each item after it's shown so that no questions are repeated, I've tried using `[thisArray removeObjectAtIndex:r];`, but the items still show. Any ideas?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"initialquestions" ofType:@"plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"The file exists");
    }
else {
    NSLog(@"The file does not exist");
}

NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"The array count: %i", [thisArray count]);

for (int i = 0; i < [thisArray count]; i++) {

    id obj;
    int r = arc4random() % [thisArray count];
    if(r<[thisArray count]){
        obj=[thisArray objectAtIndex:r];
    }
    else{
        //error message
    }

     QuestionTitle.text = [[thisArray objectAtIndex:r] objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];

     [btnA setTitle:[[thisArray objectAtIndex:r] objectForKey:@"A"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnB setTitle:[[thisArray objectAtIndex:r] objectForKey:@"B"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btnC setTitle:[[thisArray objectAtIndex:r] objectForKey:@"C"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [thisArray removeObjectAtIndex:r];

}
```

Comment: try printing the count inside for loop

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about this to test if my loop works correctly, and it did thank you. Because of my for loop the array counts down from 5 to 1 itself. I am wondering however I can make each question load correctly into the uilabel and buttons inside my loop. Would you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your array is shrinking, you need a reverse for loop :

```
for (int i = [thisArray count]-1; i > -1 ; i--) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: The reverse loop does a better job than my original for loop that I had created to count the items in my plist from 5 down to 0, however I am still at a loss of how I can make each of these items appear in my uilabel (as a question) and my uibuttons (as three answers), and move on to the next question when one is answered. I know this is a different topic from the title of the thread but any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need use `thisArray` as an property. So that its value is kept throughout the program/methods. And call the above method when question is answered. Each answer will call the above method and only one question will be removed from `thisArray`. Still some doubt, you can ask :)

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't realise that the array was not being retained and was basically reset every time. This all works great but obviously it will crash when the array becomes empty. I tried to use:
`if (thisArray == 0) {
     NSLog(@"Your array is empty");
}`

..but this does not work.